# Pine lowest low with variable, dynamic length

Tags: pine-script

I want to find the lowest low between the entry and the exit of the trade for a long position. Therefore the lowest low has a dynamic length, but Pine gives me some errors:
The function 'ta.lowest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.
The chart itself cannot be plotted. The error message references to max_bars_back, which does not make a lot of sense.

This is the extract of my code:

```
var maeLong         = 0.0
var maxMaeLong      = 0.0
var sinceTrade      = 0

if strategy.position_size != 0
    sinceTrade  := sinceTrade + 1
if strategy.position_size == 0    
    sinceTrade  := 0

if strategy.closedtrades[0] > strategy.closedtrades[1] and strategy.position_size[1] > 0    
    sinceTrade          := sinceTrade[1]                                                    
    maeLong             := (open[sinceTrade] - ta.lowest(low, sinceTrade)) / open[sinceTrade]
    maxMaeLong          := maeLong > maxMaeLong ? maeLong : maxMaeLong
```

The solution from Pine https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-functions-support-dynamic-length-arguments-20554/ could not help me.

I have the feeling, the "if strategy.strategy_position_size != 0"
is not counting in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your thinking is correct, even if we are able to move your lowest function from the local scope, the problem arrises where we ask too many bars of the function which brings about the error you described. So I present another alternative. Here we use a custom function by yours truly to find the lowest value of something since something else occurred. We will use low as an input, and we will use the change in position size to long as the bool input. The function will assign the value at first occurrence, then take the minimum value between that, or the source until a condition is detected again. I have included a plot function as to observe and verify the low point during your long trade.

```
lowestSince(src, cond) =>
    var float hi = na
    hi := cond ? src : math.min(hi, src)

long = strategy.position_size > 0 

enterLong = long and not long[1]

lowestLow = lowestSince(low, enterLong)

plot(long ? lowestLow : na, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Cheers and best of luck in your trading and coding

Comment: Thank you! I am not yet well familiar with functions, so please allow me a follow-up question: As I want to calculate the Maximum Adverse Excursion of all my trades, I used your function and added it to the last if condition, where I still use sinceTrade.

Comment: `if strategy.closedtrades[0] > strategy.closedtrades[1] and strategy.position_size[1] > 0
    sinceTrade := sinceTrade[1]
    maeLong := (open[sinceTrade] - lowestLow / open[sinceTrade]
    maxMaeLong := maeLong > maxMaeLong ? maeLong : maxMaeLong`
But as you said, my countig does not work. Is there a workaround for this?
The second question is regarding entry and exit without a low, if I use your function. If the market between these two points is increasing bar by bar, there is no low and this could lead to an error, I suppose.

Comment: did you even try it? No there is no work around for max bars back. This function gives the lowest low during a long trade. It seems you are complicated the question... https://www.tradingview.com/x/Auhkc3BZ/

Comment: I do not use any longer sinceTrade as I just save the open price when entering a new trade. Makes it work! Your function is quite smart by the way. But why do you call the var "hi" as you are looking to a low?

Comment: That was a mistake - adapted from my highestSince function and I forgot to change it. My apologies